# Querying TFS 2015 Source Code Repository with Powershell and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: powershell, tfs-2015, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create a Powershell script with Visual Studio 2019 that accesses a particular Team Foundation Server 2015 team project and one of its branches. The goal is to return the names of files that have been either created or modified within a specific time period.  To accomplish this, I am under the impression that I must filter for the .CreationTime and .LastWriteTime properties.

I have successfully accessed the project collection with the  [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client] API, but fail to access individual team projects when using the version control repository instantiation   [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer]. Authentication has been ensured but no vcs methods recognize the repository paths. (I purposely omitted the assembly declarations from the code below.)

```
    $tfsCollectionURI =[System.Uri]'http://tfs.infosys.com:8080/tfs/collection/'
    $projectsCollection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfsCollectionURI)

   if($projectsCollection.HasAuthenticated)
  {
       $vcs = $projectsCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])
      }

            $projectPath = 'http://tfs.infosys.com:8080/tfs/collection/
            project/_git/Enterprise'
    $vcs.GetAllTeamProjects($true)
    $vcs.GetTeamProject('EHBs')
    $vcs.GetItems($projectPath)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your shared code, you are trying to get the wrong projectPath.

`http://tfs.infosys.com:8080/tfs/collection/project/_git/Enterprise` This seems like a url in web portal of git repo.

However you code are used for **TFVC version control**.  The project path should be something as `$/MyFirstProject/Main-branch2.0-child1`

You could use [this rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) below to find Git Repos in a team project:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}?api-version=4.1
```

And you could use GET Invoke-RestMethod to execute REST API in Powershell, for PowerShell REST API Programming, please refer to the following link:

https://wilsonmar.github.io/powershell-rest-api/

Comment: I was able to access the GitItem class with the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebAPI library.  This returns file-level properties.